# Can a subscription billing platform be used without a database?

Tags: java, database, recurring-billing

I need to integrate a subscription billing platform into my software. Examples of this are [Pabbly](https://www.pabbly.com/subscriptions/) or [Recurly](https://recurly.com/). There are loads out there, and generally they all work in a similar way and include APIs for a developer to use. Which I choose doesn't particularly matter for this question I don't think.

In terms of the software it is a Java application that a user runs on their own computer. Currently I keep no database of users and the software is free.

I need to add a subscription model to the software so that a user can pay for, enabling particular features to be available to them.

The question is, can the software in combination with a subscription platform be used without a database (other than the database the billing platform is using)?

If possible I would like to avoid storing any customer data. Can I just use the APIs provided and the information stored by the billing platform to have the functionality I need?

My initial thoughts are that the user can enter their details via some kind of portal. Which are sent to the billing platform, then depending on the state of their subscription the software would generate some kind of encrypted key which expires with the subscription. Would something like that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer, I work for Recurly). What you are looking to do could be achievable with our software. Events inside of Recurly trigger webhooks, which you could consume to update access and provisioning on your side. Any API calls you submit to Recurly would also give you an API response that contains all the information you'd need to provision an account.

For example, when a customer subscribes, you'll get XML in response that indicates the plan they signed up for (ie, what features to give) and when the bill period ends (when you might remove access). If the customer ever has a payment issue, we'll send you a webhook, so you would know to remove access (and perhaps put up a past due banner) until they pay.

Take a look at https://docs.recurly.com/docs/webhooks and https://dev.recurly.com/page/webhooks#dunning-event-notifications as a starting point, and let us know if you have more questions!

Comment: Thank you for this information, it's certainly helpful. I'll have a look into the documentation.